# VoiceOver - Don't say the position of UISlider

Tags: ios, accessibility, uislider, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have an `UISlider`, which has a VoiceOver label.

VoiceOver says the position of the slider in percent, but I have values between 5 ans 20, and I want to say these to the user.

How do I stop VoiceOver from saying the position automatically?

Comment: Are you changing the `accessibilityValue` of the slider?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist No, I'm changing the ``accessibilityLabel``

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you still have this issue but I found that by setting .accessibilityValue  = "" that the app stopped reporting the slider value.